# Errors after installing Android Studio 3 update

Tags: android, android-studio

I've upgraded yesterday from Android Studio 2.3.3 to stable version 3 and I regret the moment.

First I had bunch of errors because of Crashalytics and Answers so I had to reinstall them.

Then I couldn't run the app because I got "No SDK" error so I launched the SDK setup again.

And Then I got bunch of errors related to values and AAPT2:
[image: value errors, there are many more]

[image: AAPT2 errors]

The thing is that yesterday I had those errors and I updated my dependenceies to match 26.0.2 from 25.0.3 And every thing worked fine.
But after I had to kill android studio process and relaunched, I got those errors again.

Please help

Comment: Since you moved to build tools 26.0.2 make sure you have the following in your project level gradle `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`

Comment: I have it and had it before.